# 5 Minute circle timer which will work when user opens the page

Tags: javascript, appgyver

I need to add 5 Minute circle timer which will work when user opens the page JS custom code in AppGyver. I found a ready code https://codepen.io/SabAsan/pen/zYvpZPM just help me to correct the code little bit, exactly the design of this circle [as in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiNeA.png) and write them as one JS code because  Appgyver accepts just JS custom code https://docs.appgyver.com/app-logic/custom-javascript

[Here's the Axelor JS code type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNQ8Y.png)

```
  function CountDown(duration, display) {
        if (!isNaN(duration)) {
            var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
            
          var interVal=  setInterval(function () {
                minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
                seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                $(display).html("<b>" + minutes + "m : " + seconds + "s" + "</b>");
                if (--timer < 0) {
                    timer = duration;
                   SubmitFunction();
                   $('#display').empty();
                   clearInterval(interVal)
                }
                },1000);
        }
    }
    
    function SubmitFunction(){
   $('#submitted').html('submitted');
    
    }
    

     CountDown(3,$('#display'));
```

Comment: Your question is hard to read.

Comment: and now?
I need to add 5 Minute circle timer which will work when user opens the page JS custom code in AppGyver. I found a ready code https://codepen.io/SabAsan/pen/zYvpZPM just help me to correct the code little bit, exactly the design of this circle as in the image and write them as one JS code because Appgyver accepts just JS custom code https://docs.appgyver.com/app-logic/custom-javascript